# How to calculate angle from velocity of moving pivot (pendulum)?

Tags: physics, angle, processing.js, pendulum

I am trying to simulate pendulum with moving pivot in processing.js. My question is, how to calculate angle at which my pendulum swing (while pivot is moving), based on pivot velocity? I searched all the web, but there angle is always known in equations. Is there any equation to calculate this from moving?

Comment: 1) It doesn't make physical sense that the instantaneous angle should depend on the pivot's movement (perhaps you meant that of the *bob*?) 2) Why not determine it from the position of the bob?

Comment: Please note that Processing.js was discontinued in December of 2018 (and at the time of retirement, was years behind in Processing support, only supporting API v2, rather than v3). For alternatives, have a look at [p5js](https://p5js.org) instead.